# Can someone tell me what to do to eliminate this value error in the following python code?

Tags: python, matrix, vector, random, numbers

Can someone tell me what to do to eliminate this value error in the following python code? It's a python matrix code; executing multiplication in a matrix (dot matrix)

```
import time
user_pref = np.array([5, 1, 3])
movies1 = np.random.randint(5,size=(3,1000))+1
for num_movies in (10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000):
    movies = np.random.randint(5,size=(3, movies1))+1
    now = time.time()
    np.dot(user_pref, movies)
    print (time.time() - now), "seconds to run", movies, "movies"
```

```
   ValueError
   Traceback (most recent call last)
        ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2652/2907248673.py in <module>
              1 import time
              2 for num_movies in (10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000):
        ----> 3     movies = np.random.randint(5,size=(3, movies1))+1
              4     now = time.time()
              5     np.dot(user_pref, movies)
        
        mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.randint()
        
        _bounded_integers.pyx in numpy.random._bounded_integers._rand_int32()
        
        ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Results that I expect after a successful run of the code:

```
    0.000160932540894 seconds to run 10000 movies
    0.00121188163757 seconds to run 100000 movies
    0.0105860233307 seconds to run 1000000 movies
```

Comment: Is it successful or not?

Comment: What are you expecting when you pass a float array in the parameter `size` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't really understand how to use `np.random.randint`. In your program `movies1` is a `numpy.ndarray` and you are not expected to pass `size=(3, movies1)` like that. Check this out for more info: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html.